# use a validation function for an element in apex 5.0

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to implement a validation on an application item in APEX 5.0.  I am using a PL/SQL function returning a boolean

```
begin
  if exists (select id_referencia 
               from items
              where id_referencia = :P2_REFERENCIA) 
  then
    return true;
  else
    return false;
  end if;
end;
```

When I submit my page, I get the following error

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 4: PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column
>   'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only ORA-06550: line 2,
>   column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if exists` isn't valid PL/SQL syntax.

You could do a `count(*)` instead

```
declare
  l_cnt integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from items
   where id_referencia = :P2_REFERENCIA;

  if( l_cnt >= 1 )
  then
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
  end if;
end;
```

If you really wanted to do an `exists`, you'd do something like this.  I don't know why you'd want to do this assuming that `id_referencia` is the primary key of the table. But you could

```
declare
  l_exists integer;
begin
  begin
    select 1
      into l_exists
      from dual
     where exists( select 1
                     from items
                    where id_referencia = :P2_REFERENCIA );
  exception
    when no_data_found
    then
      l_exists := 0;
  end;

  if( l_exists = 1 )
  then 
    return true;
  else
    return false;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: that's work well but dont found the id_referencia this is a char type on my data base and does not a primary key, i dont know if the problem is when i get the type on the text field, because probing the query show me the result fine, i apreciate all your help thanks a lot @JustinCave

Comment: @DavidNeira - I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.  Yesterday, you said it was successful.  Today you say it "work well" but if it's not finding the value, that would seem to be the opposite of working well.  Which version of the code are you using?  Is `id_referencia` really a `char`?  Or a `varchar2`?

Comment: i am sorry i think the code works, but i want it found the query, but i do the query in the sqlplus and it found it but put in the validation on apex and it doesnt found it, id_referencia is a char type indeed, expect put my point out view clear to you @JustinCave

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use EXISTS in a PL/SQL function returning BOOLEAN,try this

```
DECLARE
  v_exist NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT 1 
INTO v_exist
FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (select id_referencia 
                                 from items
                                 where id_referencia = :P2_REFERENCIA)

  IF v_exist IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    RETURN true;
  ELSE
    RETURN false;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You have forgotten to add the `into v_exist` statement in your query.

Comment: This solution shows me another error :/
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06550: line 5, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 14, column 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimi ORA-06550: line 17, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Comment: You'd need a semicolon after the `select 1`.  You would also need an exception handler around your `select 1`.  If the item doesn't exist, no rows would be returned and you'd have to catch the `no_data_found` exception.

Comment: I took your warnings and put the following code

DECLARE
  v_exist NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT 1;
INTO v_exist
FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (select id_referencia 
                                 from items
                                 where id_referencia = :P2_REFERENCIA)

  IF v_exist IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    RETURN true;
  ELSE
    RETURN false;
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No se encontraron items');
END;

but it show me the following error
ORA-06550: line 5, column 9: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected ORA-06550: line 5, co...
@JustinCave

Comment: @DavidNeira - When I say that you'd need a semicolon after the `select 1` I mean at the end of the statement (i.e. after `:P2_REFERENCIA)` and before the `IF`).  Not literally after the 1.  You'd also want the exception handler to be around the `SELECT` statement not around the entire block.    If you really want the `exists`, I added it to my answer.